# How to modify url in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, url-rewriting

I need to change the url of an MVC website. The url looks like this:

```
Product/SubCategories/14?selected=ARO-240-244-2.7 D&category=Suspensie %2F Directie&engineId=33497
```

I need all these informations in the url, only without "selected =", "category=", "engineId=". The separator should be "/", not "&"
It should be like this:

```
Product/SubCategories/14?ARO-240-244-2.7 D/Suspensie %2F Directie/33497
```

Can you advise me how to achieve this?
In the view I have this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SubCategories", "Product", new { selected = selected, id = @c.ID, category = @c.CategoryName, engineId = engineId }, Request.Url.Scheme)" class="list-group-item bg-success">
```

I use this route:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
         "Childrens",                                           // Route name
         "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                            // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "Product", action = "SubCategories" }  // Parameter defaults
      );
```

Thanks!

Comment: The url in your route needs to be `"Product/SubCategories/{id}/{selected}/{category}/{engineId}"` (and it needs to be located before the default route or any other matching route).

Comment: Thanks! It works. Now it looks like this: /Product/SubCategories/94/Audi-60-1.5/Filtru aer/43423‌%E2%80%8B. I don't know why these characters: %E2%80%8B  appears. Can you help me on this?

Comment: [What is %e2%80%8e](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%25E2%2580%258B&oq=%25E2%2580%258B&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.888j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=what+is+%25e2%2580%258e&*)